# Android: Using Camera2 to light LED torch reliability

Tags: android

I wrote a simple flashlight app (using Camera) object a few years back and it was anything but simple because it did not work on a number of devices due to the way the manufacturers implemented it.  You needed to detect the device manufacturer and handle the torch based on manufacturer.

I am thinking of creating a new app that also uses the torch.

My question is this:  Is this still a problem when using Camera2? If it is still a problem, is there any resource that can help me get the torch working on most devices?